# How to update chef with knife solo?

Tags: chef, chef-solo, knife

I ran `knife solo bootstrap [myserverssh]` to initially install recipes on my server. Everything got installed correctly.

I then made changes the recipes. I ran `knife solo cook [myserverssh]` to update my server. Chef however doesn't seem to find the changes/update the server. The output is:

```
Checking Chef version...
Starting Chef Client, version 11.4.4
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 0 resources
Chef Client finished, 0 resources updated
```

**Is there something I need to do to let chef know what changed and what it needs to update ont the server?**

---

The change I made was adding the following to the site-cookbooks/nginx/recipes/main_conf.rb:

```
# Make Secure Site
template "#{node['nginx']['dir']}/sites-available/default-secure" do
  source "cakephp-secure-site.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 00644
  notifies :reload, 'service[nginx]'
end

# Enable Secure Site
nginx_site 'default-secure' do
  enable true
end
```

---

Side note: I'm also using librarian. Not sure if it makes a difference. I tried running `librarian-chef clean` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ha! Figured it out.

First time I did `knife solo bootstrap [ec2's public address]`. Second time I did `knife solo cook [ip address of my server]`.

The second time it created a new nodes file (in the nodes/ folder). It was empty and didn't have any recipes/roles assigned to the host.

I copied the content of the first node file into the second.